# Laravel 5.0: Change the name of an uploaded file

Tags: php, laravel, file, laravel-5

I have a file which I'm uploading, but the name doesn't appear to change. I would like to rename the file which I upload.

```
if ($request->hasFile('cv')){
    $file=$request->file('cv');
    $fileName= $user->lastName + date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $destinationPath=config('app.CVDestinationPath')."/cv";
    $uploaded = Storage::put($destinationPath, file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));
}
```

This piece of code works properly in uploading, but it does not rename the file. How would I make the name of it to $fileName?

Comment: Doesn't look like you're applying the `fileName` variable anywhere to me. Double check your code?

Comment: @GMR516 yea I'm just getting the `$fileName` but I do not know where to put it which will make the file have a name of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the filename to the destination path like so

```
// note concatenator in PHP is `.` and not `+`
$fileName= $user->lastName . date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$destinationPath=config('app.CVDestinationPath')."/cv/$fileName";
```

Comment: It should be ()."/cv/". $fileName

Comment: @SreejithBS I assume you dont know that PHP expands `$variables` inside a double quoted string literal automatically

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1) Get `file` extension

2) Concatenate `userlastname` , `date` and `file_extension`

3) Assign `fileName` in `destinationPath`

```
if ($request->hasFile('cv')){
    $file = $request->file('cv');

    $file_extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); //** get filename extension
    $fileName = $user->lastName . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . $file_extension;

    $destinationPath = config('app.CVDestinationPath')."/cv/".$fileName;
    $uploaded = Storage::put($destinationPath, file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));
}
```

Hope it's helpful.